# Is it possible to preset a text in tkinter entry box and if that entry box is clicked the preset text disappears?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

in tkinter you can preset a text in an entry box with inserting the text, but the problem then is, that you have to delete that preset text, if you want to input some other text without the already preset one. Its really hard for me to describe it, but I hope you understand what I mean. Basically I want a preset text in an entry box, but if the entry box is clicked, then I want the preset text to disappear. Is that possible in tkinter?

Comment: The general term for this functionality is *placeholder text*, you'll find various other answers here under that search term.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_entry = tk.Entry(window)
my_entry.insert(tk.END, "default text")
my_entry.pack()
my_entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda a: my_entry.delete(0, tk.END))
```

When the entry widget is clicked, it gets cleared